# Given that disjunct is a synonym for disjoint, what is the logical connection between a "disjunction" and "disjoint sets",?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, terminology

Both use "disjunct", but I don't see how they relate to each other, less so how it connects to the logical "inclusive or" operation.

Comment: Because the [Coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Coordinating_conjunctions) "or" translates usually the latin [vel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vel#Latin) (inclusive) and not the latin [aut](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aut#Latin) (exclusive).

Comment: What are "disjunct" sets? Do you mean *disjoint* sets?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA if it referred to xor exclusively, i would understand. i dont udst what disjunct has to do with inclusive. its rather the opposite.

Comment: @bof sorry for the mixup in professional terminology. disjunct is a dictionary synonym for disjoint. i udst what disjoint sets mean, i dont udst how a "disjointed" operator refers to the inclusive or.

Comment: It was a "decision" starting with modern mathematical logic (end 19th Century) that the "inclusive" use of "or" was more important and the "exclusive" one were secondary.

Comment: See Alfred North Whitehead & Bertrand Russell, [Principia Mathematica to #56 (Cambridge UP, 2nd ed.1927)](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA6), page 6: "The Logical Product is a propositional function with two arguments $p$ and $q$, and is the proposition asserting $p$ and $q$ *conjunctively*, that is, asserting that both $p$ and $q$ are true. The Logical Sum is a propositional function with two arguments $p$ and $q$, and is the proposition asserting $p$ or $q$ *disjunctively*, that is, asserting that at least one of the two $p$ and $q$ is true."

Comment: Both terms: disjunction and disjoint derive from Latin [*disiunctio*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disiunctio): separation.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA got it, thank you very much!

Comment: Does this mean "disjoint set" and "disjunctive set" are the same?

Comment: @kate disjoint and disjunct are synonyms, a disjunctive set appears to be something else https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_monoid#Syntactic_equivalence